# Issue with Cluster on Visual studio code (F5) on Node.js v6.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, node-cluster

I have some issue with **Visual studio code** with **Cluster**

**Edit**

If I hit **Ctrl + F5** it works correctly, what it's doing other than just **F5**, do I need to start command always with Ctrl?

**---**

It seems like workers never starts when started with VS Code Launch command **(F5)**. Do I need to do some changes to .vscode/launch.json file to make Cluster work proberly.

Actual code is copied from Node.js 6 api https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster

**npm test** Windows Command prompt shows this:

```
Master started
Listening port 80
Listening port 80
Listening port 80
Listening port 80
```

**VS Code (F5)** Debug Console show this:

```
node --debug-brk=7601 --nolazy index.js
Debugger listening on port 7601
Master started
Debugger listening on port 7602
Debugger listening on port 7603
Debugger listening on port 7604
Debugger listening on port 7605
```

**VS Code launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",

    ..........
```

**index.js**

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    console.log('Master started')
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
} else {
    // Workers can share any TCP connection
    // In this case it is an HTTP server
    http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('hello world\n');
    }).listen(80);
    console.log('Listening port 80')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The 2nd workaround described by weinand in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3201 works for me:

> Launch node from a terminal and attach to it with the VS Code
>   debugger.
>
> Run in terminal: node --debug app.js
>
> Then select the default 'attach' launch config and
>   attach to it.
>
> The workaround is the preferred way if you actually want to debug any 
>   worker and not just the first process that is launched.

Comment: for development and only debugging the master you can do: 
    process.execArgv[0] = process.execArgv[0].replace('-brk', '');

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Visual studio code with Cluster.

I found that there are some dirty method to make it works.

**Mac OS X:**

> /Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node-debug/out/node/nodeDebug.js

**Windows:**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node-debug\out\node\nodeDebug.js

Change this

```
if (!this._noDebug) {
    launchArgs.push("--debug-brk=" + port);
}
```

to

```
if (!this._noDebug) {
    launchArgs.push("--debug=" + port);
}
```

I know it is not the best way to solve it, but it is working so far for me.

Comment: this just simply won't enable debugger and none of the breakpoints will be hit